# How can I find English words among the names of the characters in the Mathematica character set?

Tags: string-manipulation

I want to find some single meaningful words in the "ASCII/Unicode" form characters.

For example, I want to get `alpha` from `\[Alpha]`.

```
\[Alpha] // FullForm
```

> ```
> \[Alpha]
> ```

here there are two ways:

### method 1

---

Obtain all `FullForm` such characters list, and get the words, and check the validity/

```
{"\[Alpha]", "\[Function]", "\[Beta]"} // FullForm
```

> ```
> List["\[Alpha]","\[Function]","\[Beta]"]
> ```

```
wordlist = StringCases[
            ToString[FromCharacterCode[Range[0, 200]], CharacterEncoding -> "ASCII"],  
            Shortest["\\["~~x__~~"]"] /;(Length@DictionaryLookup[x, IgnoreCase -> True]                   
                                         >= 1) -> x
                      ]
```

> ```
> {Cent,Sterling,Currency,Yen,Section,Micro,Paragraph}
> ```

The above code becomes too slow at `Range` is `20000`, so how to speed up it, and extend the characters(some maybe not in `FromCharacterCode[Range[0,65536]`) such like "`\[Function]`" this is the  **question1** .

### method 2

---

I have a `wordlist` to check the validity.

For example, `alpha`, then convert it into the right string form.

we can check by `ToExpression`, the problem is `ToExpression` sometimes returns too many errors for some wrong string.

Something like a function `SyntaxQ`(which failed at such characters `\[Function]`)

```
SyntaxQ["\\[Function]"]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

```
wordlist = "\\["<>StringJoin[MapAt[ToUpperCase, Characters[#], 1]]<>"]" & /@     
           DictionaryLookup["*"];

Select[wordlist, SyntaxQ] // Union
```

> ```
> {\[Alpha],\[Andy],\[Angle],\[Angstrom],\[Bet],\[Beta],\[Breve],\[Bullet],\[Cedilla],\[Cent
> ],\[Chi],\[Continuation],\[Copyright],\[Currency],\[Dagger],\[Dash],\[Degree],\[Delta],\[D
> iameter],\[Earth],\[Ellipsis],\[Epsilon],\[Eta],\[Euro],\[Flat],\[Florin],\[Gamma],\[Hyphe
> n],\[Infinity],\[Iota],\[Jupiter],\[Kappa],\[Lambda],\[Mars],\[Mercury],\[Micro],\[Moon],\
> [Mu],\[Natural],\[Neptune],\[Nu],\[Null],\[Omega],\[Omicron],\[Paragraph],\[Phi],\[Pi],\[P
> laceholder],\[Pluto],\[Prime],\[Psi],\[Rho],\[Rupee],\[Saturn],\[Section],\[Sharp],\[Sigma
> ],\[Spooky],\[Sterling],\[Stigma],\[Sun],\[Tau],\[Theta],\[Thorn],\[Trademark],\[Upsilon],
> \[Uranus],\[Venus],\[Villa],\[Wolf],\[Xi],\[Yen],\[Zeta]}
> ```

```
% // Length
```

> ```
> 73
> ```

So, I just found 73 words, that's too little.

I think/hope there is a list(maybe some files) for such "ASCII"/Special characters.

**question2**  is to set up from a `wordlist` I wanna to check.

### References

---

Of course we can import such help pages to get all such words, but I'd like some way like `Names["*"]` to get all such codes, that's much faster.

[guide/SpecialCharacters](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/SpecialCharacters.html)

Comment: You can consider that I want to count the vocabulary in the SpecialCharacters. Good Night. Hope not so bad to understand.

Comment: Sounds like you want the unicode names list: http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/NamesList.txt  Note that Mma doesn't support anything above FFFF.

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, I think part of special characters are NameList of unicode, I'm not sure whether that's all the same in Mathematica, maybe some special characters are unique in Mathematica?

Comment: No, it's not the same.  So what you want is precisely their Mathematica names?

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, Mathematica names, sometimes I use `fn` to Enter `\[Function]`. and I learned a word called `function`, that help me know some new words.

Comment: If you have a character, `FullForm` tells you its Mathematica name.

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, So I showed that in my question, I want to have all such characters. :)  just try to import unicode characters?.

Comment: How about this? `FullForm@FromCharacterCode@
  Select[Range[2^16 - 1], 
   StringMatchQ[ToString@FullForm@FromCharacterCode[#], "\"\\[*"] &]`

Comment: I think it's much better to generate the characters(I see the `Function` in it.) I'll do some more check it into it. good night. Maybe you can put it into a answer firstly, thanks:) if I have further question, then notify you.

Comment: I just noticed that your list contains "Andy", which my list does not, likely due to the fact that I sent all words to `DictionaryLookup` in lower case.

Comment: I just want to share a blown-up view of the "Andy" glyph, which I think is an interesting find. An experimental logo glyph for "Wolfram _Mathematica_"? [Andy.png](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOEAU.png)

Comment: Strange; it's completely blank in v7 on my machine.  Since this admittedly is not an answer perhaps you could post this as a comment, image link included of course?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard This is blank for me in plain weight, but not in bold weight.  Try `Style["\[Andy]", FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 72]`.  Is it still blank?  I get the same glyph with `\[Spooky] \[Akuz] \[Villa]`.  Whoever put these names there must be having a chuckle at how people are trying to guess the meaning ;-)

Comment: @Szabolcs still blank in v7.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Windows v9 gives a plain box. Linux v9 gives blank.  I wonder if this glyph is just OS X's way of saying, "unknown character in private use area".

Comment: @Mr.Wizard & m_goldberg: actually that seems to be the case.  [See here](http://superuser.com/questions/35225/weird-symbols-on-mac) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallback_font#The_Unicode_Last_Resort_Font)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building on an example from the documentation of `FromCharacterCode`,

```
c = Select[ToString[FullForm[FromCharacterCode[#]]] & /@ Range[65535],
    StringMatchQ[#, "\"\\[" ~~ ___] &];
Length[c]
Grid@Sort[
  Partition[Riffle[c, ToExpression[c]], 
    2] /. {a_, b_} :> {StringTake[a, {4, -3}], b}]
```

> 923

Partial output, in alphabetical order

[image: special chars]

---

**Which of the special characters are English words (in lower case)?**

```
DictionaryLookup /@ (%[[1, All, 1]] // ToLowerCase) // Flatten
```

> {"alpha", "and", "angle", "angstrom", "backslash", "because", "bet", 
>   "beta", "breve", "bullet", "cap", "cedilla", "cent", "chi", 
>   "cloverleaf", "colon", "conditioned", "congruent", "conjugate", 
>   "continuation", "copyright", "cross", "cup", "curl", "currency", 
>   "dagger", "dash", "degree", "delta", "diameter", "diamond", 
>   "distributed", "divergence", "divide", "divides", "earth", "element", 
>   "ellipsis", "epsilon", "equal", "equilibrium", "equivalent", "eta", 
>   "euro", "exists", "flat", "florin", "formals", "function", "gamma", 
>   "gradient", "hyphen", "implies", "infinity", "integral", 
>   "intersection", "iota", "kappa", "lambda", "mars", "mercury", 
>   "micro", "minus", "moon", "mu", "natural", "nor", "not", "nu", 
>   "null", "omega", "omicron", "or", "paragraph", "perpendicular", 
>   "phi", "pi", "piecewise", "placeholder", "precedes", "prime", 
>   "product", "proportion", "proportional", "psi", "rho", "rule", 
>   "rupee", "scripts", "section", "sharp", "sigma", "spooky", "square", 
>   "star", "sterling", "stigma", "subset", "succeeds", "sum", "sun", 
>   "tau", "therefore", "theta", "thorn", "tilde", "times", "trademark", 
>   "transpose", "union", "upsilon", "villa", "wedge", "wolf", "xi", 
>   "yen", "zeta"}

```
Length[%]
```

> 117

---

**Which of the special characters are English words (in upper case)?**

`DictionaryLookUp` recognizes the following special characters in Upper case:

> {"Andy", "Angstrom", "Chi", "Colon", "Cross", "Delta", "Jupiter", 
>   "Mars", "Mercury", "Moon", "Neptune", "Pluto", "Saturn", "Sharp", 
>   "Sterling", "Thorn", "Union", "Uranus", "Venus", "Villa", "Wolf"}

Of those it recognizes the following ONLY in uppercase: the name of a man and the names of the planets in our solar system.

> {"Andy", "Jupiter", "Neptune", "Pluto", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Venus"}

Comment: I wonder if the `\[Andy]` character has anything to do with @AndyRoss (easter egg?)

Comment: There's also `\[Villa]`, `\[Akuz]`, `\[Spooky]`

Comment: @Szabolcs I wonder why those characters didn't appear.

Answer (score 4):

Why not to open `SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/UnicodeFontMapping.tr` and import these characters and their codes?

The list of names can be loaded in the following way

```
Join @@ StringCases[#, "[" ~~ x__ ~~ "]" :> x] & @
 Flatten @ Import @ 
   FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, 
     "/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/UnicodeFontMapping.tr"}]
```

931 words

Answer (score 2):

Here is the first part of David's answer in a more concise and efficient form:

```
StringCases[
  ToString @ FullForm @ FromCharacterCode @ Range @ 65535,
  a : ("\\[" ~~ Shortest[x__] ~~ "]") :> {x, ToExpression["\"" <> a <> "\""]}
] // Sort // Grid
```